# Jenkins Publish HTML Report - The webpage cannot be found HTTP404

Tags: jenkins

I have installed the plugin Publish HTML Reports and in the Post-build Actions section I have added:

```
HTML directory to archive : I copied and pasted the path of the C drive report folder here
Index page[s]: index.html
Report Title: Test Report
```

After I ran a build I click on the Test Report link but the page says:

```
The webpage cannot be found HTTP404
```

Am I missing some steps? My Jenkins version is 2.78.

Comment: Is that index.html file available in the path which you have provided?

Comment: Yes the file is there.

Comment: The content of the index.html file is now visible on Jenkins but the links inside does not respond when you click on them. I have checked the IE restrict ActiveX Control and those links are working if I open the index file on its own in a browser. It only does not when I open it in Jenkins. Any solution to this?

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy